# How can I specify an absolute file path in log4net, with a datePattern?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I want log files to be written to a directory where log files are kept. I'm using a RollingFileAppender with a datePattern. Here is what I have that doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="x:\Logs\log" />
        <immediateFlush value="true" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

I'm hoping this will result in something like:

```
x:\Logs\log-20211026.log
```

Instead I get

```
x:\Logs\log
```

Examples that I've seen use no path, e.g.:

```
<file value="log">
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
```

Is there a way to have the data pattern, and an absolute path, and ".log" at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Someone at my work had the answer:

The file name should contain the extention and 2 additional properties need to be set:

```
<file value="x:\Logs\log.log"/>
<preserveLogFileNameExtention value="true"/>
<staticLogFileName value="false"/>
```